# How do I know where clouds form from a skew-T diagram?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, clouds

I should know where clouds form in the atmosphere from the skew-T diagram below. The anwer should be that there is a big stromcloud from a height of 300hPa to 900hPa, but I don't get why.

My reasoning was as follows: the left black line is the dew point temperature, while the right black line is the actual air temperature in the atmosphere. The blue line represents a particle that rises adiabatically from the ground. As long as the blue line is on the right of the right black line, the temperature of the air parcel is higher than the temperature of the surrounding air and the parcel keeps rising. This means an air parcel keeps rising adiabatically until it reaches a height of 930hPa.

But the air is only saturated from 300hPa to 600hPa, because only there the air temperature is close enough to the dew point temperature.
Why is it then that clouds form above that height? Is it because the saturated air is lifted up due to convection (the air parcel keeps rising until 930hPa)?

[image: Skew-T]